# Organic Groups Help

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have a website where only users I select can join. When they join I put them in one of three groups.

Team A, Team B, and Team C.

The group is private and the content inside the group is private.

I have a content type called "Announcement" that is a group content. (as seen below)

[image]

Any member in a team can create content for that specific team. I also need any member in that team to be able to edit any "Announcement" even if it isn't there own. (as seen below)

[image]

Create new Announcement: works
Edit own Announcement: works
edit any Announcement: **doesn't work**
Delete own Announcement: works

I'm having trouble troubleshooting this issue, and it's an integral part of my website. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organic groups global permissions (path admin/config/group/permissions) have to be set as well to grant privileges to group roles (in your use case you probably only need to use the default "member" one).

This way the same user could have "administrative" rights in one group and "normal" rights in another.